# Is it possible to get a table from SAS to R?

Tags: r, sas

I use SAS to get some table from my database.
can I copy the SAS code into to R studio and to get the table to r studio?

I don't mean to upload a SAS file to R, I mean to run some SAS code in R and to get the data
directly to R

TY

Comment: No SAS and R are two different languages, though you can like modify your code quite easily, see [SAS to R guide](https://github.com/asnr/sas-to-r) for generalized help

Comment: There seems to be a macro to call R from SAS: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313844646_SUBMIT_R_A_Macro_to_Interface_SAS_and_R

Comment: Nope, there's no package for RStudio that supports this that I'm aware of at the moment.

Comment: Are you running SAS Viya or SAS 9.4?